# Ray.intersectObjects() always comes up no hits

Tags: three.js

I've created a sphere and the centre of the sphere is located at 0,0,0.

The radius of the sphere is 9.

I've created a cube that is positioned above the surface/faces of the sphere.

When I click on the cube and then proceed to click on any point on the surface of the sphere my cube will rotate it's relative position to the point clicked on the sphere (to look in the direction of the point so to say) and then it will move along the surface of the sphere towards the point clicked.  The rotation and movement all happen within a render loop.

What I want to do is cast a Ray from a point relative to the cubes position but at a greater distance to the centre of the sphere.  So for instance if the distance to any given point on any given face of my sphere is ~8.8 - 9 (of course the vertices would be at a distance of 9 and the centre of any face would be ~8.8 - 8.9)  The distance of my cube from the centre of the sphere is 9.1.  I want to cast a ray from about a distance of 12 towards the centre of my sphere.

So, if my cube is located at 0,0,9.1 then I want to cast a ray who's origin would be 0,0,12 and who's destination would be 0,0,0.  Then only target the sphere as the object to intersect, determine the distance to any given point along any given face and then set the distance of the cube to 12 - someDistance.  That way it would seem as though the cube is actually moving along the surface of the sphere.  And if I modify the features of the sphere, the cube would appear to move along the contours of the surface.

Here is my code which is located inside of a looping render function.
Unfortunately it turns up nothing.

```
var direction = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
var origin = new THREE.Vector3(object_cubi[x-1].posiX, object_cubi[x-1].posiY, object_cubi[x-1].posiZ);
origin.normalize();
origin.x *= 12;
origin.y *= 12;
origin.z *= 12;
var disRay = new THREE.Raycaster();
disRay.ray.set(origin, direction);
var rayIntersect = disRay.intersectObjects( targetList );

document.getElementById("test7").value = rayIntersect.length;
```

rayIntersect.length is always 0.
What am I missing?

To select the cube and pick a point on the surface I had to use raycaster and that code works fine.  However it does incorporate projector().

Answer (score 0):

all I needed to do was cast the ray from the centre of the sphere and make the material of the sphere double sided.

```
material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
```

Now my cube moves along the contours of my sphere.